# Comparing two sets of dates in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to compare two sets of dates(D1&D2 and A1&A2) in VBA. I would like to know their location relationship in timeline and assign a new set of a start date and an end date on different conditions. **I attached a picture to explain their possible  relationships in a timeline and how I want the new set of dates assigned.**

I tried to write a bunch of 'if sentences' for different conditions but they could not work with the loop used to get a new set of A1 and A2.

Is there any chance to have a simpler way of comparing those dates?

[image]

I added a sample code here. Thanks!!

```
Sub time()
  Dim D1, D2, A1, A2 As Date
  Dim N1, N2 As String
  Dim i As Integer

  For i = 1 To 4
    If A1 < D1 Then
      If A2 < D1 Then
        GoTo NextIteration
      Else
        If A2 < D2 Then
          N1 = D1
          N2 = D2
        End If
      End If
    Else
      If A1 < D2 Then
        If A2 < D2 Then
          N1 = A1
          N2 = D2
        End If
      Else
        GoTo NextIteration
      End If
    End If

NextIteration:
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe doing this with some IF/ElseIf and using `Exit For` inside those two conditions is the right way to go. Can you share your code and some example data that you are looping through so we can better understand?

Comment: @JNevill Thank you! I ve added a sample code

Comment: I've rewritten a bit. It's still "sample" but the `If` block logic matches what you are after. The only thing I don't see covered here is if A1 starts before D1 and A2 ends after D2 (The period defined by `D` occurs fully within the period defined by `A`). Perhaps that isn't a possibility though.

Answer (score 0):

This is closer to the spirit of what you are after. Obviously these variables need to be defined and whatnot, but the logic should make the rest of the work easier

```
sub time() 
    Dim D1 As Date, D2 As Date, A1 As Date, A2 As Date
    Dim N1 as Date, N2 As Date
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 4
        'Doesn't take into account where A1 starts BEFORE D1 and A2 ends AFTER D2
        If A2 < D1 OR A1 > D2 Then 'occurs wholey before or after d-period
            'do nothing so the next iteration occurs without any changes
            'really you don't need this check, but it might help for debugging.
        ElseIf A1 < D1 AND A2 > D1 AND A2 < D2 Then 'intersects with d-period, but starts before
            N1 = D1 
            N2 = A2
        ElseIf A1 > D1 AND A2 < D2 Then 'occurs fully within d-period
            N1 = A1
            N2 = A2
        ElseIf A1 < D2 AND A2 > D2 Then 'intersects with d-period, but ends after
            N1 = A1
            N2 = D2
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is so helpful!